# android tab host not refreshing data

Tags: android, tabs

I am using a Tab host two show two list on two tabs but I want that when click on second tab then it should reload the first tab data.How is it possible?
My code is like this

```
TabHost tabs = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost_spices);
    tabs.setup();`enter code here`
TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabs.newTabSpec("tab1");

    tab1.setContent(R.id.list_spices_fav);
    tab1.setIndicator("Favorite",getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_fav_icon));

    tabs.addTab(tab1);

    // create tab 2
    TabHost.TabSpec tab2 = tabs.newTabSpec("tab2");
    tab2.setContent(R.id.list_spices_categories);

    tab2.setIndicator("View List",getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_cat_icon));
    tabs.addTab(tab2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a tutorial,This Help me- [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

Extends your activity with TabActivity

TabHost tabHost;

```
tabHost = getTabHost(); 
Resources res = getResources();
TabSpec tabspec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("").setIndicator("Tab1",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)).setContent(new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class));
    tabHost.addTab(tabspec1);

TabSpec tabspec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("").setIndicator("Tab2",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)).setContent(new  Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
    tabHost.addTab(tabspec2);
```

Comment: i am not using tabactivity i am using tabhost inside dialog class?

Answer (score 0):

For refreshing the data of new Tab you have to keep the code for refereshing the data inside `onResume()` of that Activity because when TabActivity is created its all the tabs make a call to the respective Activities calling its `onCreate()'. So, when you click the Tab once its loaded its`onResume()`method is called and not`onCreate()`.

Comment: How to use onresume in class that extending dialog class?please tell